# Simple PHP script (without MySQL) for jQuery UI Autocomplete

Tags: php, jquery, regex, jquery-ui, autocomplete

I have the following HTML with jQuery:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Test</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../scripts/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
    <link href="../scripts/ui/jquery-ui.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../scripts/ui/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
            $("#acInput").autocomplete({
                source: "autocomplete.php"
            })
       })
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="ui-widget">
        <label for="acInput">Flower Name: </label><input type="text" name="acInput" id="acInput">
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

and I want to create a PHP file (autocomplete.php which would be in the same directory) that will search through array and return response:

I've tried the following way:

```
<?php
$flowers = ["Aster", "Daffodil", "Rose","Peony", "Primula", "Snowdrop", "Poppy", "Primrose", "Petuna", "Pansy"];
$matches = [];
if (isset($_GET["term"])) {  
    $term = trim($_GET["term"]);  // do I need to remove/strip tags or escape it and what is the best way?
    if (!empty($term)) {
        $pattern = '/^'+$term+'/';
        foreach ($flowers as $cvet) {
            preg_match($pattern, $cvet, $matches);
        }
        echo json_encode($matches);
    }
}
```

But it doesn't work. I assume that the problem has to do with *$pattern* or *preg_match*, since this is the first time I use regular expression with PHP?

**EDIT:** What I want is to check:

**1.** Are there values in the array $flowers that are equal to $term OR start with $term;

**2.**  Are there values in the array $flowers containing $term.

Return all of these $flowers array values (elements) to jQuery autocomplete and display them as suggestions. Thanks!

Comment: *"But it doesn't work."* - Not much for us to go on here. Are you checking for errors? Have you looked at your console?

Comment: And what do you really try to achieve with your regular expression?

Comment: @Gennadiy Litvinyuk I edited the question, I hope it is now clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would rather give you a much simplified version, without using `regex`:

```
<?php
  $flowers = ["Aster", "Daffodil", "Rose","Peony", "Primula", "Snowdrop", "Poppy", "Primrose", "Petuna", "Pansy"];

  // If the `term` is set.
  if (isset($_GET["term"])) {
    $flowers = array_filter($flowers, "filter_out");
  }

  // Callback function for the array to filter only those values contain the term.
  function filter_out ($var) {
    return strpos($var, $_GET["term"]) !== false;
  }

  // encode and send it back.
  echo json_encode($flowers);
```

**Output**

Request: `autocomplete.php`
Response

```
["Aster","Daffodil","Rose","Peony","Primula","Snowdrop","Poppy","Primrose","Petuna","Pansy"]
```

Request: `autocomplete.php?term=p`
Response:

```
["Snowdrop","Poppy"]
```

Comment: I'm getting `Warning: strpos() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given`

Comment: It is also more secure, because you don't have to escape Regex.

Comment: @Praveen Kumar Ok, no errors but I do not get any response. For example, when I type "a" - nothing happens. Here is the screenshot of firebug net panel: http://s14.postimg.org/59fqhx5lt/autocomplete.png    Also, please see the my question (EDIT) - What I want is to check: **1.**  Are there values in the array $flowers that are equal to $term OR start with $term;  **2.** Are there values in the array $flowers containing $term. Return all of these $flowers array values (elements) to jQuery autocomplete and display them as suggestion. Thanks!

Comment: @PeraMika Can you show the response content, please?

Comment: @PeraMika Check my updated answer. Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: @Praveen Kumar Yes, thank you! I would just add strtolower: `return strpos(strtolower($var), strtolower($_GET["term"])) !== false;`, but anyway - it works. Again, thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

$flowers = ["aster", "daffodil", "rose","peony", "primula", "snowdrop", "poppy", "primrose", "petuna", "pansy"];

$matches = [];

if (isset($_GET["term"]) && !empty($_GET["term"])) {  
    $term = trim( strip_tags($_GET["term"]) );  
    if (!empty($term)) {
        $pattern = '/^'. strtolower($term) .'/ui';
        foreach ($flowers as $cvet) {
            preg_match($pattern, $cvet, $m);
            if(isset($m[0])) $matches[] = $m[0]; // or ucfirst($m[0]) (if you want)
        }
        echo json_encode($matches);
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm getting `Notice: Undefined offset: 0`

Comment: Constructing pattern from user input without escaping open your server to ReDOS. Better escape it properly with `preg_quote(..., '/')`